# Working with wxpython NoteBook event

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a NoteBook in wxpython as follows:

```
self.a = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=0)

self.x= firstpanel(self.a,None)
self.y= secondpanel(self.a,None)

self.a.AddPage(self.x,_("firstPage"))
self.a.AddPage(self.y,_("secondPage"))

self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED,self.ChangedTab)
```

In `ChangedTab` I want to change a Button named `bttn` in the screen. if `secondPage` tab was clicked then button will be clickable (`bttn.Enabled()` )  if any other tab was clicked button will be unclickable (`bttn.Disable()`).

What I have so far is:

```
def ChangedTab(self, event):
     index = event.GetIndex()
```

My problem is how do I know which tab was clicked?

I know the tabs by their names `firstPage` and `secondPage` etc.. how do I get them from the event? The `GetIndex()` doesn't seem to help me in this case. or there is another way to do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetPage`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BookCtrlBase-class.html#GetPage) to get the selected page object, then you can compare it with the second page object (`self.y`) to check if the second tab is selected:

```
def ChangedTab(self, event):
    index = self.a.GetSelection()
    if self.a.GetPage(index) is self.y: # second page
        # Enable button
    else:                               # other pages
        # Disable button
```

Comment: It gives an error: expected argument 2 of type 'size_t'